# compare last period (week) score with current period score in rails 4 App

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on an App where I have to compare to scores from one user but the scoring is from different periods( grouped by week), here is the scenario

So each week a user get a performance review  and a number of scores are assigned to his performance, if we are in week 5 the review is for week 4 (the previous week). So during this session a new target is set for that week based on previous performances.

So what i want is current the creation/ review of the previous week the set target should be displayed somewhere either on the new or show view.

Since  rails doesn’t have a .prev or .next out of the box how can I access the target set in the last weeks scores ans display in the new weeks view.